# WebClient UploadFile to PHP $_FILES?

Tags: c#, php, upload

I am uploading a file to PHP on a CentOS host using a C# WebClient() as follows:

```
            using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
                NameValueCollection parameters = new NameValueCollection();
                parameters.Add("computer", _mach_name);
                parameters.Add("ipadr", _localIP);
                wc.QueryString = parameters;

                byte[] bret = wc.UploadFile(url, "POST", schFile);
                string sret = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bret);
            }
```

I have two separate computers using the exact same code above so they both send the same schFile to PHP $_FILES but I can tell which computer by _mach_name and _localIP.

My PHP code to receive this file is as follows:

```
$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$storeFolder = 'schedule';
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
$time = strtotime(" ");
$time = date("M,d,Y h:i:s A");

$test = print_r($_FILES, true);

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) {
    $name = $_GET['computer'];  //get the computer name so I know if this is the north or south side schedule
    $ipadr = $_GET['ipadr'];    //get the computer ip address - another way to tell whos schedule this is
    file_put_contents("upload_schedule_debug.txt", "time: $time   name: $name   ip: $ipadr    _FILES:  $test\r\n", FILE_APPEND);

    $error = $_FILES['file']['error'];
    if($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;

        //Add computer name to front of schedule filename - ie SV-North-PC_player_schedule.db3 / SV-South-PC_player_schedule.db3
        $filename = $name . "_" . $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $targetFile =  $targetPath . $filename;
        move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile);
        //$_FILES = array();  //clear the $_FILES
    }
}
```

}

This code above worked for several months just fine - then recently started picking up an old previously upload file not the most recently uploaded file? So what happens is it switches between the old outdated uploaded file and the new correct just uploaded file? I don't know why it is doing this can anyone help? Here is my debug from the file_put_contents(…)

```
time: Jun,21,2019 09:40:00 AM   name: SV-North-PC   ip:
192.168.203.102    _FILES:  Array (
    [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => player_schedule.db3
            [type] => application/octet-stream
            [tmp_name] => /var/www/www-root/data/mod-tmp/phpYUCDQZ
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 9216
        )

)

time: Jun,21,2019 09:40:06 AM   name: SV-South-PC   ip:
192.168.203.103    _FILES:  Array (
    [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => player_schedule.db3
            [type] => application/octet-stream
            [tmp_name] => /var/www/www-root/data/mod-tmp/phpG25EYe
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 7168
        )

)

time: Jun,21,2019 09:40:07 AM   name: SV-South-PC   ip:
192.168.203.103    _FILES:  Array (
    [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => player_schedule.db3
            [type] => application/octet-stream
            [tmp_name] => /var/www/www-root/data/mod-tmp/phpfTPhdC
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 7168
        )

)

time: Jun,21,2019 09:40:13 AM   name: SV-South-PC   ip:
192.168.203.103    _FILES:  Array (
    [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => player_schedule.db3
            [type] => application/octet-stream
            [tmp_name] => /var/www/www-root/data/mod-tmp/phppqHvD6
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 10240
        )

)

time: Jun,21,2019 09:40:13 AM   name: SV-South-PC   ip:
192.168.203.103    _FILES:  Array (
    [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => player_schedule.db3
            [type] => application/octet-stream
            [tmp_name] => /var/www/www-root/data/mod-tmp/phpqhOHFH
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 10240
        )

)

time: Jun,21,2019 09:40:21 AM   name: SV-North-PC   ip:
192.168.203.102    _FILES:  Array (
    [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => player_schedule.db3
            [type] => application/octet-stream
            [tmp_name] => /var/www/www-root/data/mod-tmp/phpN0DdNK
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 7168
        )

)

time: Jun,21,2019 09:40:21 AM   name: SV-North-PC   ip:
192.168.203.102    _FILES:  Array (
    [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => player_schedule.db3
            [type] => application/octet-stream
            [tmp_name] => /var/www/www-root/data/mod-tmp/phpVIiSuD
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 7168
        )

)

time: Jun,21,2019 09:40:30 AM   name: SV-North-PC   ip:
192.168.203.102    _FILES:  Array (
    [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => player_schedule.db3
            [type] => application/octet-stream
            [tmp_name] => /var/www/www-root/data/mod-tmp/phphruWhV
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 9216
        )

)

time: Jun,21,2019 09:40:37 AM   name: SV-South-PC   ip:
192.168.203.103    _FILES:  Array (
    [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => player_schedule.db3
            [type] => application/octet-stream
            [tmp_name] => /var/www/www-root/data/mod-tmp/php6yH4Dj
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 7168
        )

)

time: Jun,21,2019 09:40:37 AM   name: SV-South-PC   ip:
192.168.203.103    _FILES:  Array (
    [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => player_schedule.db3
            [type] => application/octet-stream
            [tmp_name] => /var/www/www-root/data/mod-tmp/phpu2KuxL
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 7168
        )

)

time: Jun,21,2019 09:40:44 AM   name: SV-South-PC   ip:
192.168.203.103    _FILES:  Array (
    [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => player_schedule.db3
            [type] => application/octet-stream
            [tmp_name] => /var/www/www-root/data/mod-tmp/phphAbaWx
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 10240
        )

)

time: Jun,21,2019 09:40:44 AM   name: SV-South-PC   ip:
192.168.203.103    _FILES:  Array (
    [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => player_schedule.db3
            [type] => application/octet-stream
            [tmp_name] => /var/www/www-root/data/mod-tmp/phpR0RGMd
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 10240
        )

)
```

Comment: `...recently started picking up an old previously upload file...` what does this mean? C# uploads a file to PHP, which reads it and saves it to disk? Is there another process happening here? Is the issue with PHP parsing the uploaded file or C# sending the wrong file?

Comment: @waterloomatt - it's like move_upload_file(…) is copying an old uploaded file from some time ago? But then every now and then move_upload_file(…) copies the correct file that was just uploaded. I upload file player_schedule.db3 every 20 seconds approximately to host PHP from 2 different computers.

Comment: @waterloomatt - how do I change my webclient code which is sent from 2 different computers to $_FILES[computer1] and $_FILES[computer2] notice my debug data I output above: there is 4 different size files - 2 for SV-South-PC and 2 for SV-North-PC? I think this might be the problem?